# Need to get the most recent CaseHistory record for the particular date(Created Date) in the einstein analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, einstein, saql

I have the table like this:-

CaseNumber        CaseHistory      Created Date

```
  005            oo1              09/02/2020 
                 002              10/02/2020
  006            003              11/03/2020
                 004              12/03/2020
```

now i need only latest records(10/02/2020 and 12/03/2020) will come in my table not the record having date (09/02/2020 and 11/03/2020) for a particular case. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that CaseNumber and CaseHistory are stored as measures.  If they are stored as strings you can convert them to numbers using the [string_to_number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_string_stn.htm) function.

What might work for you is to create a string version of the case number which can be used as a partition to find the max of the case history variable.  Then you can use a filter to match the max history with the case history number.  This will then only return the rows you are looking for.

```
q = load "testStackExchange";
q = foreach q generate 'CreatedDate', number_to_string('CaseNumber',"#") as 'Str_Case_Num', 'CaseHistory';
q = group q by ('CreatedDate','Str_Case_Num');
q = foreach q generate 'CreatedDate',
max(sum('CaseHistory')) over([..] partition by 'Str_Case_Num') as 'max_history',
sum('CaseHistory') as 'CaseHistory',
count() as 'count';
q = filter q by 'CaseHistory' == 'max_history'; 
q = limit q 2000;
```